# Typecasting Objects to primitives Java

Tags: java, class, classcastexception

Basically I want to typecast the objects, based on the value stored in the hashmap as:

```
HashMap<String, Class> typesMap = new HashMap();
typesMap.put("int", int.class); 
typesMap.put("double", double.class);
```

So I have an object and I want to typecast it in one of `int` or `double`, and the object is retrieved from JSON as:

```
//opencvParamsArray = ["int", 10];
Class paramClass = (Class) typesMap.get(opencvParamsArray.getString(0));//"int"
paramClass.cast(opencvParamsArray.getInt(1));
```

And I get the error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to int

I want to know the correct way of typecasting objects to primitive datatypes?

Answer (score 4):

As any generic method `Class.cast()` cannot return primitive value. It would be better in your case to cast to boxed `java.lang.Integer` type instead. So fill your `typesMap` like this:

```
HashMap<String, Class<?>> typesMap = new HashMap<>();
typesMap.put("int", Integer.class); 
typesMap.put("double", Double.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
int i = intObj.intValue();
System.out.println(i);
```

This converts the Java Integer class into int type.

Comment: I dont know the datatype beforehand so I can't use `int i = intObj.intValue();`

Comment: @ZdaR How you know that you can call `getInt`?